# Get the vector value from these points

Tags: geometry

Question regarding Geometry.

If I have a grid of $'x' =  [-5, 5]$ and $'y' [-5, 5]$, the center is $(0,0)$ (grid size can be changed).

Now, I draw a line on that grid, I have the starting and ending positions, allowing me to find the center of the drawing by dividing by $2$.

Target is to to find two vector points  (no matter the distance, can be slight distance as of $0.1$) as shown in the image with a question marks:

[image]

Comment: Consider a line with a known slope. What is the slope of a line that's perpendicular to that?

Comment: Always 90 degrees

Comment: Yes, the word 'perpendicular' means that two lines are in a 90 degree angle. Very good. But my question is about slopes of lines. For example the graph of $y=2x +1$ has a slope of $2$. What would be the slope of a line that is perpendicular to that? It's a real number and doesn't involve degrees. This is pertinent to the problem because (I assume) you want to find the perpendicular line to the line given. I'm asking this in order to help you and to lead you to a direction that would result in a solution to the problem.

Comment: yes, i want to find perpendicular line to the line given points with question marks. Not sure I totally understand the definition of 'slope'. sorry for my English.

Comment: Okay, I'm also asking because I want to know what kinds of things you're familiar with in geometry, so that I (or someone else) can explain it in an understandable way to you. Next question: Are you familiar with vectors and dot products?

Comment: yeah, vectors are kinda position in space. dot products I am less familiar.

Answer (score 0):

A vector parallel to the black line is 
$$v=(-1,2)-(2.5,-2)=(-3.5,4)$$
A vector perpendicular to $v$ is, for example, $u=(4,3.5)$.
The mid-point of the black line is
$$m=\frac{(-1,2)+(2.5,-2)}{2}=(0.75,0)$$

(*your drawing of the mid-point is not accurate*)

Therefore, for every positive number $t>0$, the vectors 
$$m+tu\quad\hbox{and}\quad m-tu$$
are perpendicular to the black line, and point in opposite directions with respect to it.
The distance between these points will be $2t\|u\|$, where $\|u\|$ denotes the length of the vector $u$. Everything can be calculated now, and you can choose $t$ to give whatever distance you desire.

Comment: Shouldn't the last expression have $u$ instead of $v$ ? Because it was $u$ that was perpendicular ...

Comment: Yes, it should, thank you.

Comment: Thanks, @uniquesolution. Would you be kind and show a sample of the result as shown in the question (question marks) with a distance of 0.5 (for the example) as i have an issue with formula.

Comment: Another small mistake in the logic is that $v$ should be $(4,+3.5)$.  With these values, the set of points
$$
l = m + tv = \left(\frac{3}{4}, 0 \right) + t \left( 4, \frac{7}{2}  \right)
$$
,where $t \in \mathbb{R}$, covers the solution points. If you want the distance from $\left(\frac{3}{4}, 0 \right)$ to be equal to $\frac{1}{2}$, this means
$$
| t | \sqrt{4^2 + \left(\frac{7}{2}\right)^2 } = \frac{1}{2} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad t = \pm \frac{2 \sqrt{113}}{113}
$$
Giving the points
$$
\left( \frac{3}{4} \pm \frac{8}{\sqrt{113}}, \pm \frac{7}{\sqrt{113}} \right)
$$